# Is Debian 'bridge' truly equivalent to 'switch' in networking?

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge

I am new to networking 'inside' a machine with with implementation of VMs and I am a bit confused by the term 'bridge' employed in Debian OS.

When I started networking in the physical world a few decades ago, I used hubs and bridges. These physical bridges were only 2 ports interfaces and it was complicated to implement even a basic networks with them. When switches, with their multi-port capabilities and ease of use (ability to chain them without any configuration to do), became affordable, I replaced all my hubs + bridges by switches. So, 'bridge' had for me a negative value compared to 'switch'.

During my googling, articles were saying that nowadays, 'bridge' and 'switch' are interchangeable, that 'bridge' is more for software networking and 'switch' is more for hardware.

Is it really the case?

Is 'bridge' under Debian truly behave like a physical network 'switch': only the receiver interface is getting the packet, full knowledge of the network when multiple devices chained, etc.?

Comment: Switches (in this context "pure" switches, L2 devices) don't know the entire network, only their next-hop neighbors. Red Hat has a good [introduction to Linux bridging](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/04/06/introduction-linux-bridging-commands-and-features).

Comment: This SF Q/A can also be interesting: https://serverfault.com/questions/78184/whats-the-difference-between-a-bridge-and-a-switch

Comment: @Peregrino69 - my understanding is that the switch knowledge can go beyond the next hop. I think that when it receives a packet, the switch register  the MAC of the sender and the port where it received the packet. Therefore, the switch can be aware of a sender more than 1 hop away, as long as it belongs to the same network.

Comment: @a-b - thanks for the link

Comment: Not quite :-) A switch can remember for a time which port leads _towards_ a given MAC address. That's all it needs. When it receives a frame (packet is a L3 concept), it checks if the destination is in its MAC table. If not, it will flood it out of all connected ports. If yes, it will forward the frame only out of the port leading towards that MAC. It neither knows nor cares if the destination is directly connected. It can have some knowledge of the next-hop neighbor, that's all. I made a quick topology in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Hz7WN0q9) with a bit more details :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that Stephen Kitt's answer in the link he provided in the comment answers your question.

Peregrino69 also points out a useful clarification to your description of "switch".

I won't claim to know the Linux bridge source code well enough to give an authoritative answer but I could add the following:

In Debian, or more generally in Linux, a bridge would be comparable to a switch as opposed to a hub.

There is no evidence that a port added to the bridge is in half duplex mode (e.g. `ethtool veth0`), which I believe would have to be the case with a hub.  There are no statistics showing frame collisions (e.g. `ip -s -s link show veth0` or `ip -s -s link show bridge1`), which would be a normal occurrence with a hub.

A hub, which in many respects is more similar to the older thick (or thin) Ethernet, uses the equivalent to a shared physical medium which, in my opinion, would be much harder to simulate in a virtual environment, in comparison to a switch style (non-shared physical medium).  A hub does resemble a switch in the network's star shaped topology, but I think that is not relevant here.

According to [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub), IEEE has moved away from hubs:

> Hubs are now largely obsolete, having been replaced by network
> switches except in very old installations or specialized applications.
> As of 2011, connecting network segments by repeaters or hubs is
> deprecated by IEEE 802.3.

which would also give reason for the Linux bridge not to be modelled around something that is obsolete.